# How to create a `enum Router: URLRequestConvertible` with some predefined parameters

Tags: swift, enums, alamofire

I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for my requests on a library project.

I'm trying to use an `enum Router: URLRequestConvertible` to handle the routes and the queries but I've some parameters that should be set only once and some that should have default values and I don't know handle them.

## Sample code

This is what I have so far:

### My `ResultFromat` enum

```
/// Available result formats
enum ResultFormat: String {
  case XML = "xml"
  case JSON = "json"
}
```

### My `Router` enum

Here there are one parameter that is fixed and should be set upon creation (`apiId`) and one that has a default value (`resFormat`) but don't mangage to make the `init` method work.

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
  static let API_BASE = "http://sbslocal/api2/"

  /// API ID to use in the API calls
  static let apiId : String

  /// Format to receive the response
  static var resFormat = ResultFormat.JSON

  // MARK: - Enum initialzer

  init(apiID: String) {
    Router.apiId = apiID
  }

  case Search(query: String)
  case ViewDetail(id: Int)

  // ... the rest of the cases ...

  // MARK: URLRequestConvertible



   var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
    let (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) = {
      /// Set the basic URL paameters
      var params = ["apiID": Router.API_ID, "format": Router.RESULT_FORMAT.rawValue]
      switch self {
      case .Search(let query):
        // Add the specific parameters for this case (i.e. query)
        params["query"] = query
        return ("/search", params)
        // ... the rest fo the cases
      }
    }()

    let URL = NSURL(string: Router.API_BASE)!
    let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

    return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
  }


}
```

I've checked with different posibilities for the initialization but none of them seems to work. Any help woudl be apreciated.

Comment: enums don't have init methods. classes do.

Comment: they do, please read the introduction here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_221

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I see three problems with your code.

First thing is that your enum do not have any case. Not sure whether it's strictly required, but it seems like in Swift enum needs to have a case. You could just use single `case Default`.

Second thing is that you do not set `self` at your initialiser. Enum initialisers, since enums are consisting of cases, need to specify which case does `self` belong to. You can just write `self = .Default`.

Third thing is that if you are defining non-optional property, you cannot make it valueless. providing initial value for `apiId` resolves that.

After those changes your code looks like:

```
enum Router {

    case Default

    static let API_BASE = "http://sbslocal/api2/"
    static let apiId : String = ""
    static var resFormat = ResultFormat.JSON

    init(apiID: String) {
        Router.apiId = apiID
        self = Router.Default
    }
}
```

This can be used than:

```
let router = Router(apiID: "someID")
```

If this is the API that you are striving for, here it comes.

Comment: That was just a part of my enum, not to put all the code, but i has cases, I've expanded a bit the code to show it better.

Comment: @pconcepcion thanks! you still do not assign any case to `self` in `init`, have you tried it?